# Issue with include/exclude data in my stored procedure depending of parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had an issue in my stored procedure that needs to include rows or not depending on the value of a parameter

- if `@var_exclude = 'Y'` I need to show only rows that `mytable.field1 = 'N'`
- if `@var_exclude = 'N'` I need to show all rows

I'm using the following query but doesn't work properly

My code is like

```
@var_exclude    varchar(1)

    select mytable.field1, mytable.field2, mytable.field3, mytable.field4,mytable.field5 
    from mytable
Where mytable.field6 is null
  and mytable.field1 is not null
  and (mytable.state = @paramstate or @paramstate = 'ALL')
  and  mytable.field1 = Case when @var_exclude= 'Y' Then 'N' Else @var_exclude End
End
```

I'm confused!

Comment: It's called a store*D* procedure - as **stored** in SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store". Furthermore: if you have just a single character - make it a `CHAR(1)` - no need to make it a `VARCHAR(1)` (which has at least 2 byte overhead!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic handling `@var_exclude` is wrong.

When you pass `@var_exclude = 'Y'`, then your query basically gets resolved to:

```
select .....
from mytable
where mytable.field6 is null 
  and mytable.field1 is not null
  and (mytable.state = @paramstate or @paramstate = 'ALL')
  and mytable.field1 = 'N'
```

since in this case, the `when @var_exclude= 'Y' Then 'N'` part of your CASE clause is used.

If you pass anything else in, then you take the value you're passing in; so if you pass in `@var_exclude = 'N'` then your query is resolved to:

```
select .....
from mytable
where mytable.field6 is null 
  and mytable.field1 is not null
  and (mytable.state = @paramstate or @paramstate = 'ALL')
  and mytable.field1 = 'N'
```

since in this case the `Else @var_exclude` of your CASE clause is used - and since `@var_exclude = 'N'`, you get the exact same query as before....

I would probably write this procedure something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetData 
     @paramstate VARCHAR(???),
     @var_exclude CHAR(1)
AS BEGIN 
   IF @var_exclude = 'N' THEN
      SELECT
         t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, t.field4, t.field5 
      FROM 
         dbo.mytable t
      WHERE 
         t.field6 IS NULL
         AND t.field1 IS NOT NULL
         AND (t.state = @paramstate OR @paramstate = 'ALL')

   ELSE
      SELECT
         t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, t.field4, t.field5 
      FROM 
         dbo.mytable t
      WHERE 
         t.field6 IS NULL
         AND t.field1 IS NOT NULL
         AND (t.state = @paramstate OR @paramstate = 'ALL')
         AND t.field1 = 'N'
END
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I wrote like this, but I think is not to efficient becuase my query is not to simple like this sample and I've to be very carefully in the future to maintain it.

Comment: @user1004299: why not efficient?? I think it's the best you can do, really, since in one case, you have to have this additional restriction, while in the other case, you don't .... there's really no good way to model this otherwise....

Answer (score 0):

Hey in case anyone is still looking for something like this, you CAN actually do it in the where clause, you need to write an IN statement and evaluate the condition as follows:

```
DECLARE @Include bit
SELECT ISNULL(CASE @Include WHEN 1 THEN 1 END,0)
UNION
SELECT ISNULL(CASE @Include WHEN 1 THEN 0 END,0)
```

So this will evaluate to:

```
IF @Include = 1 THEN 0,1
ELSEIF @Include = 0 THEN 0
END
```

So all you have to do is write an IN clause in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM store 
WHERE values IN (
SELECT ISNULL(CASE @Include WHEN 1 THEN 1 END,0)
UNION
SELECT ISNULL(CASE @Include WHEN 1 THEN 0 END,0)
)
```

I hope this helps anyone in the future!